# Search filters not showing the right results

Tags: support, bug, search, tag-search

I recently started to use the ability to create an advanced search and have added [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3Amine%20is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0%20score%3A-1..) query to my bookmarks, which is translated to this:

[image: query I'm using]

However, for some reason, I see mostly **only `django` related questions**, I rarely see a `java`, `c#` or `javascript` question. (which are all in my tags)

It seemed strange and I clicked the [Question tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) only to see [a `javascript` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398325/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history) meeting my search criteria, but didn't appear in the filters.

As it can be seen, I added to my tag favorites the `c#*`, `java*` and `javascript*` tags, so it could be due to me using asterisk to favorite my tags.

And yesterday, using the same filters, I kept seeing a specific search result even if it was answered (and the answer got accepted) (while my filters specifically requests for **answers:0** questions)

Is this a bug or am I missing something? How should I *rewrite* my query for it to work?

Comment: hmm... i'm seeing a pretty healthy mix of results, none having answers, covering most of my favorite tags. But i have no wildcard tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due to using wildcard tags...

Comment: I [recreated a smaller version of your filter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+or+%5Bhp-uft%5D+or+%5Buft-api%5D+or+%5Bqtp%5D+or+%5Bleanft%5D+or+%5Bfunctional-testing%5D+or+%5Bpython*%5D+or+%5Bjavascript*%5D+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+score%3A-1) (reached max length in search bar) and am seeing more than just django. It starts out with a bunch of python, gets into some hp-uft, javascript, etc. 316k results.

Comment: Keep in mind these results aren't sorted either unless you click on a tab other than relevance.

Comment: This is a good alternative. Thanks!